# Object scalameter is not a member of package.org error when compiling a scala program with sbt

Tags: scala

I am trying to compile a scala project using sbt but I am getting some errors:

[Below is the screenshot of the output]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJUSz.png

Comment: Are you running sbt from the root of the project?

Comment: No, I am running it from a subfolder. I also tried to run it from the root of  the  project but I get the same error.

Comment: You must run sbt from the root of the project (where the `build.sbt` file or `project` directory containing sbt settings is)

Comment: Should I run any other command before compile?